# Eventlistener for child window opened by extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a extjs code to create a window

```
var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',{
    title : headerMsg,
    width : 350,
    height : 250,
    layout : 'fit',
    plain : true,
    buttonAlign : 'center',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'box',
        autoEl : {
            tag : 'iframe',
            src : 'some.asp',
            height : '100%',
            width : '100%',
            style : 'cursor:pointer;top:10px'
        }
    }
    ]
});
window.show();
}
}));
```

in some.asp I have a button

```
<button class="stdbutton" onclick="windowClose();" id=button2 name=button2>
```

I dont know how to create an asp in fiddle but i created the extJS please check the followinf link :

```
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14bj
```

Imagine i have a button(button ID: button2) on src : 'ccc.de';, and when i click that button I should catch the event in js Thank you

I should not made any changes in asp like adding onClick() function..etc

what I tried is adding

```
$("#button2").click(function() {
alert("button2 clicked");
});
```

works in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/30w751ew/3/  but didnot worked for me

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I cant see the code, but, did you add the jquery reference `<script>`

Comment: sorry, I didnt get you what do you mean by that I added the code in question and also in snecha fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the script code to your html for adding query:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Your fiddle don't have it, but the query library could be being loaded from fiddle webpage thats why it works on your fiddle.

Comment: I should not made any changes to my asp or html

Comment: In your previous fiddle you showed us an example of html and jquery thats worked on fiddle but don't for you. Explain better please

Comment: Hi, what I mean is the eventListener 

$("#button2").click(function() {
alert("button2 clicked");
});

worked in fiddle but not working for me. the reason i guess is because i am creating the child window using extjs and trying to listen event from that window

Comment: Ok, I know only a bit about ExtJS, but It seems `$("#button2").click(function() { alert("button2 clicked"); });` is jQuery. If you don't reference in a way to jQuery it will never work.

Comment: In the asp, at the end of the body you can add the `script` metatag and then you have the reference to jQuery